# Is it possible to call external SOAP/REST API in ExactTarget?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

Is it possible to call external SOAP/REST API in ExactTarget? I want to call external SOAP/REST API in landing page and need to use [SSJS](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/). I tried to search in ExactTarget [wiki](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/) but didn't get any proper documents.

I'm wondering if there is an documents/solution for the external SOAP/REST API, and if not, perhaps some suggestions on another way to solve this. Thanks for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: What is your use case here?

Comment: I want to retrieve the subscriber preference details using SOAP API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really no different than any other platform used for making API calls.  How would you build your API call to fetch subscriber preferences in a [LAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)) or [IIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) environment?

If the API action needs to be on a SFMC Landing Page or Microsite, then you'll have to do it within the confines of SFMC's [SSJS](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/) and [AMPScript](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/api_ampscript_functions/) functions.

If you need to do an HTTP Get on a public endpoint, then you can use the [SSJS Get()](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/http_server_side_javascript_functions/) or the AMPScript [httpGet()](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/http/HTTPGet.html) functions.